# Uncheck 'Do not store password. The task will only have access to local resources"

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, windows-task-scheduler

I'm creating Scheduled Job via Powershell but I can't set this options/setting to either create Task without 'Don't store password. The task will only have access to local resources' or change it afterwards.

I've written the following code to create scheduled job, but task is created with checked setting 'don't store password' and it does not have access to local network. I don't want to change it manually via Task Scheduler GUI.

```
$task_path = 'path to file'
$scheduled_job_options = New-ScheduledJobOption -WakeToRun -StartIfIdle -ContinueIfGoingOnBattery 
$scheduled_job_triggers = New-JobTrigger -Once -At "10:00AM" -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Hours 6) -RepetitionDuration ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue) 
Register-ScheduledJob -Name "Collect Logs" -FilePath $task_path -ScheduledJobOption $scheduled_job_options -Trigger $scheduled_job_triggers -Credential $credential
```

[image]

I've also tried to remove supplying credentials, but it doesn't change anything. How to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "but I can't options/setting to either create Task without 'Don't store password."

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I meant, that I can't find the way how to manage this Task setting via PowerShell.

Comment: It's still really unclear to me what you're trying to do and what's happening. You say you can't "set this options/setting" - *which* "options/setting"? What is stopping you from setting it? I have to say, this doesn't really sound like a programming question - it may be better for SuperUser...

Comment: I've edited my initial question. This is a programming question, but looks to be a tricky one. Also, tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32727042/5148934) advise, but it didn't help.

Comment: Ah, it's *much* clearer now that you've shown what you mean.

Comment: Yeah, it's better to give as much details as possible, I know...

Comment: So, any ideas folks?